# How can Upgrade MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.4

Tags: mysql

How can I Upgrade MySQL version

Current MySQL Version:  5.7.22

Target MySQL Version: MySQL 8.4

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to perform that upgrade.

If you have only one server, then you could just perform an INPLACE upgrade ( [INPLACE upgrade here](https://mysqlserverteam.com/inplace-upgrade-from-mysql-5-7-to-mysql-8-0/) ). The idea is to upgrade the packages and perform an upgrade of the data.

If you prefer to install a new MySQL 8.0 fresh install and import your data, then you may try the LOGICAL upgrade : [LOGICAL upgrade here](https://www.activcloud.eu/news/20181004-mysql-57-80-logical-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

> The server can be upgraded by performing either an INPLACE upgrade or
>   LOGICAL upgrade.  The INPLACE upgrade involves shutting down the MySQL
>   5.7 server, replacing the old binaries with MySQL 8.0 binaries and then starting the MySQL 8.0 server on the old data directory.  The
>   LOGICAL upgrade involves exporting SQL from the MySQL 5.7 version
>   using a backup or export utility such as mysqldump or mysqlpump,
>   installing the MySQL 8.0 binaries, and then applying the SQL to the
>   new MySQL version.

The following link may also be useful

[this link from askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7)